# How to include Java Source code within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, plugins

In Netbeans, I can see the built-in sourse code of Java by clicking on `LeftClick` + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and the `.java` file is shown:

[image]

But when I do the same thing in Eclipse, the following is shown:

[image]

How can include the source code within Eclipse? I need Java 7 source code if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the [source](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7/) and then clicking the "Attach Source" button in the screenshot you posted?

Comment: Thanks, I am downloading it now +1

Comment: If it worked in Netbeans, on the same PC, then you already had the source code somewhere. You might have it twice now.

Comment: It is Java 6 source code anyway that is attached to netbeans ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could attach source manually, but the easier method would be to switch Eclipse to use the JDK instead of the JRE... in which case it will discover and attach the sources that came with the JDK for you.

You can do this by going to your Eclipse Preferences (`Window > Preferences`) then under `Java > Installed JREs` you can click the `Search` button. Point it to your `c:\Program Files\Java` and let her rip.

You'll then see all the installed JREs and JDKs in there. You can use the checkbox to set your workspace default to the preferred JDK. You can use the `Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments` to ensure that when you have a project building against something like `JavaSE-1.7` you force the correct Java installation (this is how [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) typically configures the classpath...).

Existing projects in your workspace (if they're setup to use an explicit JRE instead of an Execution environment or the workspace default) you may have to switch as well by right clicking on the `JRE System Library` and changing it to a configured Execution environment or JDK.

Clear as mud? :)